# How to get parent dynamic id in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In regular way we do a dynamic url and get the id from the URL. but let's do a nested dynamic route like someurl.com/[slug]/[id]. now we have a way to get the id for this right? but how do we get the slug?

Comment: If you are using latest app router you can achieve this using [catch all segments]
  [1]: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes

Answer (score 0):

In Next.js, you can retrieve the URL parameters from the dynamic route using the `useRouter` React hook. For example,

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const Post = () => {
  const router = useRouter()

  if (router.isFallback) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  const { slug, id } = router.query
}
```

`router.query` will be an empty object on the first render because Next.js has not yet populated it. It will be populated on the next render.  You can add a loading state to your component to handle this. `router.isFallback` is true while the page is loading, so you can return a loading state during this time